# WPF (VS2012): Why does the appearance of a window in the app change depending on the system it's installed on?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Screenshot evidence (both installed on Windows 10):

Developer's system:

[image: developer screenshot]

Other system:

[image: other screenshot]

Normal dialog theme on developer's system:

[image: normal dialog window]

Bright blue foreground on other system:

[image: glaring blue dialog]

First of all, let me describe the app's environment:

- The app was built with .net framework v4
- It is a Windows application
- The development environment is VS2012 (upgraded from 2010)
- The common XML namespace used throughout the layouts is "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
- The app was built originally for Windows 7, back in 2012. No developer has updated it for compatibility with Windows 8 or 10

The issue is as such: depending on the hardware configuration of the Windows 10 system the app is installed on (all systems have been proven to have the same update status, number of security and cumulative updates), the app will have varying colour encoding... appearing normal on some systems such as my own:

Developer:

- System Model WS60 2OJ
- OS Name  Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
- Processor    Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4720HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz, 2601 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)
- Graphics NVIDIA Quadro K2100M

But not for others.

Other:

- System Model Surface Pro 4
- OS Name  Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
- Processor    Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6300U CPU @ 2.40GHz
- Graphics Intel 520 @ 300 MHz on-die

This high blue channel encoding has also appeared on other systems such as an MSI GS73VR 6RF laptop.

Hopefully this provides enough info. If you'd like to know more, I will be quick to follow up. Thanks for your time and patience!

Comment: Can you describe the differences? For me, the first and the second screenshots look pretty similar.

Comment: @dymanoid Well, in the first 2 pictures, what's happening is that I have attached a loaded() listener to a DataGrid object, and on trigger, it accesses the the parent view and iterates through the cells, changing the background to green via styling. In the 3rd and 4th pictures, secondary dialog windows appear normal on my system, but on my coworker's system (and some others) the secondary dialogs always lose grayscale and become blue. EDIT: it re-styles the cell to green if the parsed value is non-zero.

Comment: Don't look like OS applying different theme. May be you are using some dynamic library loading? In this case the resource dictionaries that are loaded first would be used for conflicting styles (same keys or same target controls). But it is just a guess.

Comment: always bear in mind that it is possible for XAML to not show some exceptions. so make sure no exceptions are surpassed by XAML and also external dlls are accessible (check and unblock them one by one) https://www.thewindowsclub.com/fix-windows-blocked-access-file